# I am working on multiclass text classification, How to pass one hot encoded in to keras model for training in ytrainset?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, text-classification

I am working on text classification problem. i have 9 labels in my ytrain.but when i pass xtrain and ytrain to model , it give me error : that expected to have shape(1,) but got (9,). and my size of ytrain is (32,9). Picture of Ytrain is attachted ::

[image: ytrain image]

Below is my model :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=embedding_dim, input_length=max_len))
model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=100, kernel_size=4))
model.add(layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(layers.Dense(12, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy',precision,recall,f1])
model.summary()
```

**Traceback:**
Error when checking target: expected dense_9 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (9,)

'''

Answer (score 0):

You should convert `y_train` to the one-hot encoding. For example, you can use [keras.utils.to_categorical](https://keras.io/utils/).

Comment: I am asking something else . my arrays are already in one hot encoded form.. please check above image of ytrain . how to pass such arrays to model which have 32 rows in xtrain . and i have 32 rows as well in ytrain of one hot encoded but having 9 columns here as well

Comment: I guess, the problem in the loss function. Could you try to use `categorical_crossentropy `, instead `sparse_categorical_crossentropy `.  Also, the last Dense layer, shout has output dimensions equal to the number of the classes = you have 9 classes, but the output is 12.